# Using RavenDB as a persistent cache

Tags: asp.net, caching, ravendb

I have currently have a web application that caches a large amount of data (several hundred thousand entries) in memory for quick lookup and then in SQL Server as a persistent cache. Basically the information consists of geocodes of addresses where the geocode is retrieved via a remote web service which takes time if needed to be called continuously rather than cached.

Would using RavenDB (or other suggestions) be a better way of caching this information in a persistent store in terms of both speed and memory? Currently the app is hosted on a server which SQL Server sucks most of the memory dry so I would like a more light weight solution.

Comment: Whether one or another database is more suitable for your needs really depends on the kind of data you're talking about. Unless you give us more insight into your requirements, no one here can seriously tell you if RavenDB would be better in your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RavenDB as a document database seems overkill to me if only used as a cache. What about [redis](http://redis.io/) as a value store? It could better match what you are after

Comment: What about mongodb?!!? Super fast writes and fast reads?  Raven not bad either IMO

Answer (score 0):

RavenDb should be faster for reading than SQL. Not that writing is slow, but it's optimized for read operations as far as I know. So you should try it, it should be better performance-wise. I'm not sure about memory though.

If you want more info, you can always try the [RavenDb Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb). Ayende follows it, so he might answer himself.