# Object cache with unlimited # of keys but a limited # of objects

Tags: c#, caching

I am looking for an c# object cache library that can implement the following patterns:

- the cache is used to cache objects of a certain type T that have a primary key. Example: a Person class (with first name, last name etc) and the key is PersonId
- the cache can store an unlimited # of keys. The keys are of type int or long.
- the cache, however, can store only a limited # of objects of type T. T objects take a lot of memory and I can't have lots of these objects in the cache at a time.
- on overflow the cache can serialize the objects to a database or file etc. (fast medium) but the cache would still keep around the keys.

I basically need to process more T objects than I can keep in the memory and I want to use the cache to retrieve them quickly before I save the results to the database.

So, I was thinking of using the [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) pattern and have the cache store proxy objects that can get/serialize my real objects.

Do you know any caching c# library that can be used with these patterns? I haven't been able to find anything myself.

Thanks

Comment: what s the question exactly? There is no in memory caching package out there as far as i know. except the blogs you can see. Proxy with lazy is the way to go. Also set expiry on the cache items. and if you are limiting the cache size, do LRU impl for eviction of cache items.

Comment: Rephrased the question. I hope that it is clear now.

Comment: I don't understand how would keeping the ids in the cache help. You would need to go to the database to retrieve the actual data anyway.

Comment: If you need to access more of T then you can keep in memory then you're starting to sound like memcached/memcachedb/RavenDB is the sort of thing you're looking for. An ORM like RavenDB would almost definitely cover your bases here I think.

Comment: Difference between a distributed cache to in-memory cache is you dont have any network latency. But you have other problems. This is a very big topic, it s better if you code and experience, solve problems. Check out in-memory caching.

Comment: @svick: this cache is used to support a request for calculations. I need to keep track of all the objects involved in a request (there are interdependencies between them). Because these objects are expensive from the memory perspective, I can have only a limited # of them at one point in memory.

Comment: @Russ C- I was thinking of nosql dbs as well. For now, I am trying to avoid them.

Comment: I understand; but if you need to take your object out of your working set then you need persistance; to my mind, it's better to use something that exists and is proven rather then re-invent the wheel. Other thing to consider, if you want to keep this in memory, if its not in your applications working set, then its in another processes, ultimately it will still reduce the resources you have available.  How big are these T objects ?

Comment: By the way, related question that suggests RavenDB or red.is:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350313/using-ravendb-as-a-persistent-cache

Comment: @Russ C: I am not trying to reinvent the wheel, hence my post. I looked at RavenDB, redis and mongodb. redis is not an option because:this is a MS shop, and I also followed the redis discussions and the blogs, and basically the author wants to concentrate his efforts on the linux platform and he also decided to abandon the vm option (where he would persist the key values). Between RavenDB and mongodb I would choose mongodb because, in my tests, it is much faster.

Comment: @Russ C: To answer your last question, having ~300 objects takes ~ 900MB of memory

Comment: Sorry, I didn't intend to accuse you of re-inventing the wheel! Just trying to say that what you're trying to achieve smacks more of a two-type ORM then some kind of Cache. Assuming you have 300 live T objects, 900mb is clearly too much to keep in memory so you're going to have to find a persistance layer; RavenDB and an SSD wouldn't really be so bad - yes Raven is *better* for Reading than writing, but that's misleading too - it's not like its writing is shoddy and unsustainable. At this point, I guess some throughput/lifetime metrics would help to illuminate the choices available.

Comment: @Russ C: no worries. We are on the same page, I am trying to use something that is proven.

Comment: @RussC "900mb is clearly too much to keep in memory" why is this? One of the applications I'm responsible for can have well over 4gb of objects in memory at any given time, per server. The question should be, *why* is 900mb too much to keep in memory? Memory is cheap. The amount of time you spend puzzling over this problem could buy dozens of gigabytes of memory.

Comment: Okay, perhaps that was a bit hyperbole, but as Costa hasn't posted much about his environments - it pays to be cautious. To my mind and my experience, 900mb of managed memory is excessive and often counter productive. Also, yes memory is cheap but the fact that Costa has an issue with this means that in his context, 900mb is worth arguing about.  Don't put SO answers in the context of your own experience, try to visualise the circumstances of the person who asked.

Comment: @RexM: I will answer this question. The data that I am processing is going to grow every day. If I knew that it is fixed and or it exhibits a slow growth, I would agree would you. Potentially, the users might want to keep years of data. I don't want one day, in a year or two this app to explode with out of memory errors. So, I have to think of this problem now.

Comment: Very good point Costa; And there is also a performance thing that comes into relevance; the .Net garbage collector heap walks and compresses to contiguous memory blocks where it can; if you're keeping 4gb of objects alive then it *will* take longer for GC to run, and it is a locking process. In a managed environment chucking more RAM at a problem doesn't necessarily fix it as all of these factors are important.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a database. Database engines are made to keep key tables and object tables separate. (If you're not familiar with that concept, search the web for information on database indexing, primary keys, etc.) They're also made to keep pages of the keys tables in RAM and recently used objects in RAM. In fact, many database engines allow you to configure how much of each you keep in RAM. I think you should use Sqlite with a lightweight ORM (like Dapper or ServiceStack.OrmLite or one of a bazillion others). Sqlite has a parameter to turn off disk synchronicity and two other parameters to adjust the amount of data in RAM. See the info here:  http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html